# How to handle basic get request with json server

Tags: javascript, json-server

I have a simple json database like this

```
{
  "items": {
    "itemArray": [
      {"id": 1},
      {"id": 2},
      {"id": 3}
    ]
  }
}
```

Ordinary get request works well and returns the right data. But now I want to handle get request to change data structure of the server response, and for the very beginning i try to return the same data but through server.get method. How should it look like?

```
server.get('/items', (req, res) => {
  // ?
});
```

Tones of examples did not make the issue clear for me.

Comment: I may recommend using Express, a Node.js web application framework that provides a very useful set of features for your web applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server.get('/items', (req, res) => {
  var db = require('./db.json');
  res.json(db.items);
});
```